# Set filter parameters in pivot table present in Microsoft Excel 2010 file programatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, excel, sharepoint-2010, pivot-table

I want to set filter values in the Excel file using code and then the user will be able to download it.
I tried the approach given [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cumgranosalis/archive/2009/11/30/using-setparameters-with-the-excel-web-services-apis.aspx) but it was not setting the filter
.
I am working with Microsoft SharePoint 2010 custom webparts.
It is working fine in a console application, but when we add the same code in a webpart it is failing. Again this works for Ids and not for names in a console application.
Tried to find other approaches. Any sources would be great

Error Message: *Some of the parameters you tried to set are no longer valid parameters. As a result, none of the parameters have been set.

Parameters can become invalid if they are deleted, contain a formula, are inside another object such as a Table or PivotTable, or if their named range no longer refers to just a single cell.*

Comment: If you stick two spaces on the end of a sentence you don't have to use `<br />`.